# FuelPHP: ORM Sort by HasMany Count

Tags: sorting, orm, fuelphp

I have a table called **post** that ***HAS MANY*** **comments** I need to sort the list of post by how many comments there are in a post.

In fuelPHP, is there a way to do this in ORM? I want to make sure before I do it manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for this: No, there's not. It is not possible for the ORM to sort for you like that without doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

To work around it:

```
// construct an array with post-id => comment-count
$ordered = array();
foreach($posts as $id => $post)
{
    $ordered[$id] = count($post->comments); 
}

// order the array, largest count first
arsort($ordered, SORT_NUMERIC);

// merge the posts in, maintaining order
$ordered = array_replace($ordered, $posts);
```

This uses takes advantage of the feature that array_replace will maintain the key order of the first array.